# increase number by 1 if order_id found (localStorage)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
var obj = {};

$.each(arr, function () {
    if (obj.order_id == this.order.id) {
        obj.order_id = '1';
        obj.order_name = 'cake';
        obj.price = '$1.10';
        obj.qty = 1;
        obj.qty = parseInt(this.qty) + 1;
    } else {
        obj.order_id = '1';
        obj.order_name = 'cake';
        obj.price = '$1.10';
        obj.qty = 1;
    }
});

arr.push(obj);
localStorage.setItme('cart', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

How can I alter the quantity of an order if the order_id already exist in my localStorage? The above code snippet will insert another set of array object although the quantity part is correct.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you overwrite `obj.qty=` in both of these branches?

Comment: @VikashPandey increase number of qty by 1 if order_id found

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want to update the array value when `id` matches, don't create new object in this case.

Instead change if part of your code to -

```
$.each(arr, function(){
if(obj.order_id == this.order.id){
  this.qty = parseInt(this.qty) + 1; //Assuming you only want to edit qnty value
}
```

Also ensure you push `obj` in else block only.

Comment: this doesn't work. because u just pushed a new obj.qty to the array =="

Comment: obj object is entirely untouched. I don't know how do you see any of it's property being modified by this code.