# alter array object property then save back to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm doing a cart and I want to increment the qty if the item_id exising in localStorage.

```
<button data-item_id="1" data-item_name="cake" data-item_price="2 dollar">Add to cart</button>
```

Not sure why my below code doesn't work, it added a new object instead of increment the qty value.

```
   $(function(){

        $('button').click(function(){
           var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item_id');
           var item_name = $(this).attr('data-item_name');
           var item_price = $(this).attr('data-item_price');

            var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
            var obj = {};

            if(arr.length === 0){ // first time insert
                obj.item_id = item_id;
                obj.item_name = item_name;
                obj.item_price = item_price;

                obj.item_qty = 1;
            }else{
                $(arr,function(i){
                //doesn't work here
                   obj.item_qty[i] = parseInt(this.qty) + 1;
                });
            }

            arr.push(obj);
            localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(arr));

        });

    });
```

debug for few hours couldn't solved.

Comment: Did you mean `$.each(arr,function(i){ ...`

Comment: Like adeneo said: You forget .each, but even then it will not do what you want it to do. Is there one product on the page or there are more?

Comment: @OSDM multiple product of course.

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [increase number by 1 if order\_id found (localStorage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353445/increase-number-by-1-if-order-id-found-localstorage) // and in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353733/alter-array-object-using-loop you also referred to this, so that seems to be closely related as well. Please use _one_ question to discuss your issue, and do not spread it out over multiple questions.

Comment: @CBroe because untill now no one can answer.

Comment: Then you need to show some _patience_, instead of creating one question after the other.

Comment: @CBroe is this a hard question?

Comment: That is not the point. The point is, that you please wait until you get answers, instead of flooding this site with what is basically the same question over and over again. And if you might feel that you don’t get any (quick) answers could perhaps have something to do with the way you asked your question (or its overall quality), or you have something new to add to it – then please do so by editing your original question, instead of creating new ones about the same topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use {}  instead of [] making the `arr` contain one object per item_id and each object will get 1 added to the qty each time it is called. There is no remove in this code

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on("click",function(e){
       var item_id    = $(this).data("item_id");
       var item_name  = $(this).data("item_name");
       var item_price = $(this).data("item_price");
       var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || {};
       var currentObj = cart[item_id];
       if(currentObj){ 
         currentObj.qty++; // increase the qty by one
       }
       else { // item_id had not been stored before, create it
         cart[item_id]= { 
           "item_name" :item_name,
           "item_price":item_price,
           "item_qty"  :1
         }
       }
       localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));
    });
});
```

Comment: where you declare obj?

Comment: I just find out this doesn't work coz I have to use [], it's not just 1 single item but multiple items.

Comment: @ChintanSoni this work but how bout multiple items? use an object?

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to do like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
       var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item_id');
       var item_name = $(this).attr('data-item_name');
       var item_price = $(this).attr('data-item_price');

        var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
        var obj = {};
            obj.item_id = item_id;
            obj.item_name = item_name;
            obj.item_price = item_price;

            obj.item_qty = 1;
            detectchange = 'no';

            $.each(arr,function(i){
            if(this.item_id == obj.item_id){
               this.item_qty = parseInt(this.item_qty) + 1; detectchange = 'yes';     }
            });
        if(detectchange =='no'){ 

        arr.push(obj); }
        localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(arr));

    });

});
```

Comment: what is detect change for? that's bit funny.

Comment: The problem is in your code is that you are adding the object to the array always, so even if you only have to increase the quantity you are still adding the item. That is why I added detectchange, that means, if you changed only quantity it will not add the object to the array. It might sound funny but it works.

Comment: Highly inefficient to loop over all items when the ID likely is unique and hence can be used as key in the arr object

Comment: That was my first suggestion, when the person was asking about this in another question, but that is not what they wanted.